# What is the alternative for <apex:enhancedList> for lightning design system in order to get look and feel like Lightning List View?

Tags: slds

I have a Visualforce Page tab where I have used `<apex:enhancedList>`for displaying list view of my custom object like follow:-

```
<apex:enhancedList type="customObject__c" height="500" rowsPerPage="25" id="srvyPrgList"  rendered="{!NOT(displayStartPage)}"/>
```

When I open this Visualforce Page tab in lightning view `<apex:enhancedList` look and will be displayed like a classic sales-force view as follows:

[image]

If I have to convert this list view so as to get look and feel like lightning list view e.g like this

[image]

Anyone please advise what should be the alternative for `<apex:enhancedList`or any workaround to convert this classic view into lightning view.

Comment: if you want this view in lightning experience then you can navigate to list view using `sforce.one.navigateToList('XXX_List view ID_XXX', 'My List view', 'customObject__c');` in JavaScript.

Comment: I don't think there is an equivalent yet. I think you will have to use the [data tables design](https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/components/data-tables/?variant=advanced#react-target) in the lightning design system and code it yourself.

Comment: you can now use `lightningstylesheet=true` in apex:page as below to convert it into lightning view. `<apex:page lightningStylesheets="true">`

Answer (score 1):

Today there is no alternative for `<apex:enhancedList>`

You can have 2 workarounds:

1. by code - use [Strike](http://www.lightningstrike.io/#!/strikeDataGrid) component which is open, free and really good, and you can customize it by code to do whatever you want.
2. From within the app builder add the `Related List` component to your record page for each list that you want to use:

[image]