# apex:enhancedList stuck in Loading

Tags: visualforce, enhancedlist

I have a Visualforce page having an apex enhancedList :

```
<apex:page>
    <apex:enhancedList type="Account" rowsPerPage="25" height="300" customizable="false" />
</apex:page>
```

but it's always stuck in this Loading state
[image]

Changing the Object does not solve the problem

Does anyone have an idea?

Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**apex:enhancedList** will work properly if you are using in classic mode. If you open this page in lightning mode then it will not show list and you will get 'Loading...' status.

Try to open that page in classic mode.

Comment: Is there any way of using it in Lightning ? Or is there an equivalent ?

Comment: You can try using Related List. See post https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/178227/what-is-the-alternative-for-apexenhancedlist-for-lightning-design-system-in-o